# why I get the warning "longer object is not subset of shorter object name" when I use which() command?

Tags: r

I have data frame which called `a` and a vector `Name`. Here are part of them

```
> a[1:5,] 
            Gene_Symbol        miRNA
    18220         DUSP6 MIMAT0000256
    18221         DUSP6 MIMAT0000256
    122914         BCL2 MIMAT0000256
    2482712      NOTCH1 MIMAT0000256
    200302       CDKN1B MIMAT0000256

> Name[1:6]
[1] "ABCA1"  "ABCC1"  "ABL1"   "ABTB1"  "ACSL4"  "ACVR2B"
```

and also a vector `Name`. I'm sure that the vector `Name` is a subset of column 1 of data frame `a`,
but when I want to select the part of `a` which it's column 1 is equal to `Name`, I get the following warning :

```
"longer object is not subset of shorter object name"
```

Here is my command :

```
b<-a[which(a[,1]==Name),]
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: You probably want `b <- a[a[,1] %in% Name),]`.

Comment: This looks like a dupe but I can't find one

Comment: @Roland, they probably don't want the `)` in there

Comment: @docendodiscimus Sure. If you don't provide a reproducible example, you get to fix typos yourself. ;)

Comment: Agreed, @Roland (no offense meant)